# How make Vim Ex command pattern range start search from current line?

Tags: vim

Suppose I have a short CSS file (code below) with 2 selectors.

```
.selector1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    background-color: #ffe0e0;
}

.selector2 {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

My goal is to print all of the rules inside the next selector. The cursor is at the very beginning of the file (1st character of 1st line ). So I try:

```
:/\V{/+1,/\V}/-1 print
```

What I get is: `Backward range given`.

I researched the reasons behind that and it's that search `/` command when used as a range starts looking at the next line to the current one. So the first `{` it finds is in `selector2`, while first `}` it finds is still in `selector1`. I assume it's because Ex commands act on lines (instead of characters), while by default and `/` behaviour is to start looking at the next character (in this case next line).

For `selector2` the command would work, if the cursor was placed one line over the `selector2`, but `selector1` is on the first line and so placing the cursor line over it is impossible.

What's the easiest way to achieve the goal - print the rules from the next selector?, even if the cursor is on the first line.

Is there a way to somehow supress/overcome the default behaviour of `/` starting search at next line to the current one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` in ranges does indeed match the next line containing the pattern. From `:h :/`:

```
/{pattern}[/]   the next line where {pattern} matches
```

However, you can pass a `count` to `/`, to indicate where to start searching from. Still from the `:help`:

```
The "/" and "?" may be preceded with another address. The search starts from there. 
(...)
The {number} must be between 0 and the number of lines in the file.
(...)
Some commands interpret the zero as "before the first line" (:read, search pattern, etc).
```

---

In your case you could use

```
:0/\V{/+1,/\V}/-1 print
```

to start searching from "before the first line", ie also match it.

A more general way of matching the current line would be with `:.-/<pattern>`, meaning: "the line before the current line" (also works when the current line is the first one).

Comment: I think `.-/<pattern>` is the best answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a preliminary step:

```
:/}/;?{?+,-p
```

where you move the cursor to the next closing brace first (with `/}/`) and then (`;`) construct your range with a backward search (`?{?+`) and the line above the current line (`-`).

Answer (score 1):

if your question is how to make `/foo/,/bar/` range start from current line, you can do:

```
exec search("{")+1.';/\V}/-1 print'
```

The `search()` will search from cursor position.

For your concrete problem, you can first search closing `}` and then backwards search `{`:

```
/\V}/-1,?\V{?+1 print
```

adjust the `-1 +1` to `-n +n` for different requirements.

or do this:

```
/{<cr>
vi{
:print
```